# When should I use "@" sign while using r language:

Tags: r, grammar

Every time I miss spell this at(@) character while writing R code so what is the usage as it has a special colour so I supposed it was meant to do something useful. Any comments on that?

Comment: Try ``help(`@`)``

Answer (score 1):

The "at"-sign is used to access S4 slots. It is the equivalent of the "dollar"-sign used to access lists (of which data.frames are but one example.)

On the other hand you might be talking about its special use in certain external packages? But I'm guessing that's not going to be the case here, because that would imply that you knew quite about about R.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that helped, in my case I will now focus on grasping the S3 and S4 object types.